# DateTime::diff weired result

Tags: php, datetime, datediff, dateinterval

I use `DateTime::diff` to compare two `DateTime`, but the result is very weird as if `abs($date1 - $date2) != abs($date2 - $date1)`.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("1980-11-21 00:00:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("1981-11-20 00:00:00");
var_dump($date1->diff($date2,true)->days);
var_dump($date2->diff($date1,true)->days);
var_dump($date1->diff($date2,true)->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"));
var_dump($date2->diff($date1,true)->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"));
```

Which returns:

```
int(364)
int(364)
string(15) "00-11-30 00:0:0"
string(15) "00-11-29 00:0:0"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ukTfu)

Comment: Isn't this just the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953393/date-diff-timorrow-date?

Comment: Because there is no day 0 (only -1 and 1)? Guess

Comment: @l00k that is my guess too

Comment: But why do you expect it to be equal? It's a different amount of days if you go forwards or backwards in time. Imagine going from yesterday to today (over a year), that'd be 366 days since you have to round a whole year + 1 day. And from today to yesterday would be only 364 days for the same reason, it's whole year minus one day.

Comment: @Andreas https://3v4l.org/0rOv6 and https://3v4l.org/c0Sqi

Comment: Sorry I understood nothing of your comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct. Both date intervals represent same number of days (364). The month and date part represent the period that needs to be added to/subtracted from first date to reach second date:

```
1981-11-20 minus 1980-11-21 represents an interval of 11 month 30 day
1980-11-21 + 11 month = 1981-10-21
1981-10-21 + 30 day   = 1981-10-21

1980-11-21 minus 1981-11-20 represents an interval of 11 month 29 day
1981-11-20 - 11 month = 1980-12-20
1980-12-20 - 29 day   = 1980-11-21
```

A simpler example would be Oct 21 ... Dec 20:

- You need to add 1 month 29 days to Oct 21 to reach Dec 20 (note that month before Dec has 30 days)
- But ... you need to subtract 1 month 30 days from Dec 20 to reach Oct 21. Oct itself has 31 days which explains the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Why not subtract min from max?
Pseudo code:

```
$diff = max($date1, $date2) - min($date1, $date2)
```

That way you should always get the same and correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so just to state my comment as an answer. My guess is that this is the expected behaviour since it's a different amount of days depending on if you go forwards or backwards in time. Imagine going from yesterday to today over a year, that'd be 366 days since you have to round a `whole year plus 1 day`. And from today to yesterday (last year) would be only 364 days for the same reason, it's `whole year minus one day`. As for the solution, the option that @Andreas suggested is the way to go here.

Comment: I believe you should add "last year" again. Your answer says it's 364 days between today and yesterday, which is not true. That is 1.

Comment: No it's not. It's still AB, BA.

Comment: @Kris Roofe why is that? Sorry I don't understand. Today and yesterday are adjacent days just as 21/11 and 20/11 in your question.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I believe I did

Comment: @KrisRoofe that's actually kinda weird indeed. Could you just use `->days` for your purpose maybe? Looks like days hold the "absolute" value and other fields depend on "direction"

Answer (score 1):

The result seems wired, but is correct:
It is explained by some months having 30 or 31 (or 28) days. If you would execute this example for October

```
    $date1 = new DateTime("1980-10-21 00:00:00");
    $date2 = new DateTime("1981-10-20 00:00:00");
    var_dump($date1->diff($date2,true)->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"));
    var_dump($date2->diff($date1,true)->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"));
    var_dump($date1->diff($date2,true)->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") == $date2->diff($date1,true)->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"));
```

```
string(15) "00-11-29 00:0:0"
string(15) "00-11-30 00:0:0"
bool(false)
```

or February

```
string(15) "00-11-30 00:0:0"
string(15) "00-11-28 00:0:0"
bool(false)
```

Yet

```
var_dump($date1->diff($date2,true)->format("%a"));
```

will always show

```
string(3) "365"
```

Comment: Actually the days is same. You can check it with `$diff->format("%a");`